# Why is the reciprocal of the second Fibonacci number negative?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

The second Fibonacci number is 1, so it's reciprocal should be 1, right? Why is it that I get $-1$ when I plug in $2$ for n in the reciprocal of Binet's equation

$$\frac{1}{F_n}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\varphi^{-n}-(-\varphi)^n}$$

I think I may have messed up on the algebra when reducing but can't find any error. Please help!

Comment: $F_n = \dfrac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\varphi-\psi} = \dfrac{\varphi^n - (-\varphi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}} \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{F_n} = \dfrac{\varphi-\psi}{\varphi^n-\psi^n} = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{\varphi^n - (-\varphi)^{-n}}$

Comment: It's $\varphi^{\color{Green}{+}n}-(-\varphi)^{\color{Green}{-}n}$ not $\varphi^{\color{Red}{-}n}-(-\varphi)^{\color{Red}{+}n}$.

Comment: $F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} ( \phi^n - (1 - \phi )^n  ) \; $